# number of solution of polynomial with parameter

Tags: calculus

Given the polynomial $P(x) = x^5 - 20x^2 + a$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$, for which values of $a$ this polynomial have only one solution?

from the fact that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}{P(x)} = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}{P(x)} = -\infty$ there is $a_0$ such that $P(a_0)<0$ and $b_0$ such that $P(b_0) > 0$ so from intermediate value theorem there is at least one solution between $a_0$ and $b_0$.

now I need to prove that there is at the most one solution. I'm not really sure how continue from here. I tried to calculate the derivative of $P(x)$ so I got that $P'(x) = 0$ when $x = 0$ or $x = 2$ and it seems like when $P(2) > 0$ in other words $a > 48$ the polynomial have only one solution but I have no idea why this correct or how to explain it.

I hope someone can explain this and what is the correct way to solve this kind of problem.
Thanks in advance.

edit: by "solution" I mean root of the polynomial.

Comment: Hint: When you calculated $P'(x)$, you found out possible local extremes. After that, can you possibly try to graph this function?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "solution" do you mean "root"?

Comment: ZettaSuro: yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right into looking at the derivative:
$$
P'(x)=5x^4-40x=5x(x^3-8)=5x(x-2)(x^2+4x+4)
$$
Therefore $P(x)$ has a maximum in $0$ and a minimum in $2$. Moreover $\lim_{x\to-\infty}P(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)=\infty$.

Because of this we know that $P(0)>P(2)$. Thus three cases can happen:

1. $P(0)<0$ (and $P(2)<0$): $P(x)$ assumes only once the value $0$, for some $x>2$.
2. $P(2)>0$ (and $P(0)>0$): $P(x)$ assumes only once the value $0$, for some $x<0$.
3. $P(0)>0$ and $P(2)<0$: $P$ has three roots, one less than $0$, one between $0$ and $2$, one greater than $2$.

So, in order to find when $P$ has only one root you have to see when $P(0)<0$ or $P(2)>0$.

Since $P(0)=a$ and $P(2)=a-48$, you can conclude that $P$ has only one root if and only if $a<0$ or $a>48$.

Comment: if $P(0) > 0$ and $P(2) < 0$ or $P(0) < 0$ and $P(2) > 0$ then there is at least one solution between 0 and 2.

Comment: @EMDB1 You can say more in the first case.

Comment: egreg: can you explain what do you mean?